# Audio switched: headphones instead of speakers and vice versa

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, ubuntu-16.04, headphones

It's been a couple of months that I started to have a problem: when I plug my headphones sound is played from the speakers, and when I plug them out there's no sound at all because I can see "Headphones" as a default device from settings. So I guess they are switched.

I have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot, and it happens on both OS. I'm trying to figure out if it's an hardware problem.

On Windows, I succeded unistalling Realtek drivers and leaving the default ones, and selecting the proper device.

On Ubuntu, every time I always have to go in `alsamixer` and turn on manually the right device.

What can I do? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: If it happened on both OSes then it is related with neither. It's either defective  hardware or something  changed in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: I doubt that the BIOS/UEFI has anything to do with the audio equipment.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Don't be so sure, lots of settings in some uefis may change the ports behavior. But I'm  more inclined to the hardware failure hypothesis, of course. That it happened on different OSes means it's not software, that's the only thing  certain here.

Comment: If it is a Hardware Fault, then it is weird that it has started happening a few months ago. Why was it working correctly before? About BIOS/UEFI: has he changed anything there? Not likely. Nothing is indeed certain anymore anywhere lately. I have recently attempted to restore a certain Operating System Image on the same Laptop Personal Computer and it has failed complaining that it had been created on a _different_ Machine with another kind of BIOS/UEFI characteristic.

Comment: I don't remember changing anything in my BIOS/UEFI. What should I check specifically?